# Get Original file name in file sharing Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to implement the file sharing from other apps in Xamarin.Forms.
And I have some issues with Android implementation.

I'm referring to code of https://codemilltech.com/sending-files-to-a-xamarin-forms-app-part-2-android/.

```
if (Intent.Action == Intent.ActionSend)
            {

            var uriFromExtras = Intent.GetParcelableExtra(Intent.ExtraStream) as Android.Net.Uri;
            string path = Intent.GetParcelableExtra(Intent.ExtraStream).ToString();
            var subject = Intent.GetStringExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject);

            // Get the info from ClipData 
            var pdf = Intent.ClipData.GetItemAt(0);

            // Open a stream from the URI 
            var pdfStream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(pdf.Uri);

            // Save it over 
            var memOfPdf = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            pdfStream.CopyTo(memOfPdf);
            var docsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(docsPath, "temp");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, memOfPdf.ToArray());
            mainForms.ShareFile(memOfPdf.ToArray(), System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path));
        }
```

And I need to get the original name of shared file from File Manager.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: I wonder what does the image contribute to the question

Comment: @bradbury9 Just wanted to make it easy to understand.

Comment: I'm interested in this question as I will be implementing this for my app soon...


Agree with @bradbury9, I don't think anyone with the ability to address this question needs the picture to know what it is you're trying to accomplish. But, doesn't really hurt either I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that gets the original file name of a shared file through an intent.

```
if (Intent.Action == Intent.ActionSend)
{
     ClipData clip = Intent.ClipData;
     Uri uri = clip.GetItemAt(0).Uri;

     ICursor returnCursor = ContentResolver.Query(uri, null, null, null, null);
     int nameIndex = returnCursor.GetColumnIndex(IOpenableColumns.DisplayName);

     returnCursor.MoveToFirst();

     var fileName = returnCursor.GetString(nameIndex);
     Toast.MakeText(this,"fileName == " + fileName, ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```

Examples: [.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGyjX.gif) file and an [xls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf4KA.gif) file.

Comment: In my case, Intent.Data is null and can't evaluate the Path of it.

Comment: @EijiKimura, how did you implement the "sharing" function? Please post your share `Activity` code.

Comment: @EijiKimura, I have update my answer, please check it.

Comment: Shen, I don't understand on which file to write your workaround. We are sharing the file from default file manager to our app.

Comment: @EijiKimura, add the above code in your `MainActivity `.

Comment: I'm talking about this.

Comment: string path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/Download/zhuxian.pdf";
Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(path);
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
shareIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, uri );
shareIntent.SetType("*/*");
StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(shareIntent, "send_to"));

Comment: @EijiKimura, I write it in another app, and just use it to test whether to get the original file name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158283/discussion-between-eiji-kimura-and-york-shen-msft).